# How to use findstr to search for multiple different strings?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to convert some Bash code into a Windows batch script. One of the lines I have in my Bash script is

```
if echo "$*" | egrep -q -- '-?|-h|--help'; then
```

Basically, it searches all of the script arguments for the options `-?`, `-h` or `--help`. What I'd like to know is, how would I convert this to use `findstr` on Windows? Here is what I have so far:

```
set args=%*
echo %args:"=% | findstr %= What goes here? =% > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! (I've tried running `findstr /?` but it doesn't seem to mention anything about matching multiple strings.)

Comment: Irecommwnd to use comparison operator `EQU` rather than `==` to do true numerical comparison for `ErrorLevel`; the `==` enforces string comparison...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this:

```
findstr /c:"-?" /c:"-h" /c:"--help"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just one question: is using `findstr /c:string` equivalent to the form `findstr /c:"string"`?

Comment: Um ... yes, I presume so.  I only ever use the quoted form, and that's what I'd recommend - but I don't suppose it matters provided the search string doesn't contain spaces or special characters.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

```
findstr /r /c:"\<-?\>" /c:"\<-h\>" /c:"\<--help\>"
```

`\<` means "beginning of word", `\>` "end of word" (to prevent false positives (for example `-hello`, `--huh`, ...)

`/r` enables regular expressions to be able to use `\<` and `\>`